# how to check out of function in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i am beginner in codeigniter and want to check the out put of a function in codeigniter so that i can debug it but i am unable to do so for example here is my function in my managementmodel and i have put the slashes before the print_r function. when i want to see the result i remove these but i do not know where to see the result if in view then how please help me. thanks

```
function department()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM department ORDER BY id 
 ASC";  
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($query->result_array());exit;
    return $query->result();
  }
    function get_test_list_info()
    {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test_list ORDER BY id 
 DESC";  
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    //print_r($query->result_array());exit;
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? you want to see the output of the functions? load the model and call the functions then and print their results. if you want to pass the data to the view you should read the docs as its all there

Comment: start with :https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/index.html